# Problems connecting a simple iPhone button

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a normal rounded rectangular button in a new iPhone app (I'm an iPhone noob).  I created the button (Set Start Date) in interface builder and am trying to hook it up to my view controller (CalendarViewController) in order to change the current view.  I want to change the active view to StartDateView.

I've been looking at various tutorials and they say that you should be able to drag the "Touch Up Inside" event dot to the CalendarView.xib's "File's Owner" icon.  However, when I try to do this, I cannot highlight the File's Owner icon, only the "First Responder" one.  What am I doing wrong?

My CalendarViewController.h file looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController {

}

- (IBAction btnSetStartDate_Clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

and my CalendarView File's Owner class is set to CalendarViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the class of your File's owner set to CalandarViewController?
Also im assuming you actually have that right brace closed on IBAction.

Comment: D'oh!  It was the missing paren that you said.  I guess I'm just too used to IDEs that let you know when you make obvious syntactical errors.  XCode really doesn't alert you to stuff like this?

Comment: Errors like this only are found when you build. I recommend hitting command-B every once in a while just to catch this kind of stuff.